# Why can't navigate to web api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I use Web API for the first time to connect my mobile app to Web API.
I have MVC 5 project and I have created API folder and inside I have created `ProductsController`.

```
namespace DDD.WebUI.API
{
    public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        public string GetAllProducts()
        {
            return "Hello From WebAPI";
        }

    }
}
```

And I have tried to access this method from browser:

```
http://localhost:21879/DDD.WebUI/API/products/GetAllProducts
```

But I get 404.
It's probably something stupid but can't figure it :(
**UPDATE**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               url: "API/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );



        }
```

**UPDATE 2**
I have a little progress:
I have update `Application_Start()` with:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

In `WebApiConfig` I have:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I still store API controller in Project/Api/ProductsController
But now I can access it but still can't get value from it:

```
http://localhost:21879/api/products/getallproducts
```

But error I get is:

```
<Error>
<Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
<MessageDetail>
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'GSL.WebUI.Api.ProductsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Comment: To answer your update. If you define the mapping that way you should not use the action in the url. Try `http://localhost:21879/api/products/` and it should work. Then see the link in my answer to understand how everything works together.

Comment: try this url .. http://localhost:21879/API/products/GetAllProducts/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think looking at your update your action requires `id` which is of non-nullable `int` and you are not supplying it just modify url as `http://localhost:21879/API/products/GetAllProducts/2`  here `'2'` is assigned to `'id'` and it will work.

In WebApiConfig modify route as :

```
   config.Routes. MapHttpRoute (
            name: "DefaultApi" ,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}" ,
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter . Optional }
        );
```

Just change this Mvc Route :

```
    routes. MapRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi" ,
           url: "API/{controller}/{action}/{id}" ,
           defaults: new { controller = "Home" , action = "Index" , id = UrlParameter .Option
       );
```

with this :

```
     routes. MapRoute(
           name: "DefaultApiMvc" ,
           url: "APIMvc/{controller}/{action}/{id}" ,
           defaults: new { controller = "Home" , action = "Index" , id = UrlParameter .Option
       );
```

because otherwise Mvc and Api routes will conflict with each other...

Comment: I did like you said but again 404. Now namespace is `GSL.WebUI.Controllers`

Comment: @1110..just put breakpoint on GetAllProducts and type url http://localhost:21879/API/products/GetAllProducts it will hit breakpoint just check???

Comment: No it doesn't get in method

Comment: I did exactly like you write. If I add just that route config I can't access my other controllers. If I add config like yours with just a different name my other controllers work but API still don't. I created completly new ASP MVC 5 project and add ProductsController to Controllers folder and same again.

Comment: I have updated question I pass through 404 but now getting some parameter error. But method doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: @Exception, `UrlParameter` is for MVC controllers, this is WebApi

Comment: This answer is wrong, `id` is defined as optional so it's not needed in the url. The action starts with `Get...` so it will be picked up when doing a `GET` request and it's not needed in the url, with the routing defined in the question. All he needs is `http://localhost:21879/api/products/`

Comment: @Tallmaris..yes it is written optional in routeconfig but somewhere in action questioner is using id of non nullabe type that is why error is coming passing id will fix...

Comment: @Tallmaris...plz see updated answer i have added other explanation also but previous answer was also correct.. i doesn't deserve downvote.. thanks...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. Watch the order in which you register your routes in Global.asax.cs.

This works:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

This doesn't:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use that way of routing, you need to specify the allowed Http methods for the action:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetAllProducts()
    {
        return "Hello From WebAPI";
    }
}
```

You can get all the information regarding API routing from this link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api